# What is $65$ congruent to mod $67$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you calculate $65 \bmod 67$? I tried the Euclidean algorithm:
$67=65*1+2$ but from this I will get $-1$ but the right answer is $-2$. Can someone please help?

Comment: Note that $a \mod b = r$ if we have that $a = q \cdot b + r$ for some positive remainder $r$. Hence you try to solve $65 = q \cdot 67 + r$. What is the possible value for $r$ (if you want to find a positive $r$)? However, you can always add or substract multiples of $b$ (67 in this case).

Comment: This is a weird question. My immediate instinct was to just say $65$...

Answer (score 8):

The "right answer" is "anything of the form $65+67n$". So both $65$ and $-2$ are correct; it depends on context which one of those is more useful.

I don't see how you obtained $-1$ from the expression that $67 = 65 \times 1 + 2$; and anyway, that expression is what you would do to show that $67 \equiv 2 \pmod{65}$, rather than answering your question.

Answer (score 4):

Definition:

> $$a\equiv b\mod n\iff n\mid(a-b)$$

So $65\equiv -2\mod 67$ because $67\mid (65--2)$.

Answer (score 4):

$65\equiv 65+k\cdot 67\pmod{67}$ for any integer value $k$.

In particular when $k=-1$ we have

$65\equiv 65+(-1)\cdot 67\equiv 65-67\equiv -2\pmod{67}$

That is to say...when talking about numbers modulo $n$, the number $x$ is equivalent to any number which can be achieved by adding or subtracting integer multiples of $n$ to it.